# Assumptions in Conventional Finance

Tags: economics, assets, price-theory, behavioral-finance

These are the 3 main assumptions used in Conventional Finance:

- Price of assets are correct, ie equal to it's intrinsic value
- Resources are allocated effectively
- World is fair and so are the market *(Adam Smith's Invisible Hand*)

Why did the modern economist started off with an unrealistic assumptions, mostly an antonyms of the world functional? 
Does the improved economic theory like **Behavioral Finance** fully have a correction mechanism for such assumptions? (human being not a rational one)

Comment: All models are wrong, but some are useful. E.g. assuming that markets are efficient is a useful assumption, most of the time.

Comment: As others have stated, all 3 are wrong, especially with Adam Smith's book from 1776. May I suggest to start from Efficient Market Hypothesis (EMH) and beyond?